# Is it possible to import a project in Kony visualizer enterprise edition which was created in Kony quantum?

Tags: javascript, visualizer, temenos-quantum

Can a project created by Kony quantum to be opened by Kony enterprise edition?

I have already tried and got the attached error, knowing that the version I use for both editions are 8 SP 4 as shown in the image

> Unsupported project version
>
> This project has been upgraded to the "Version 9 Service Pack 3 Fix Pack 4" version of visualizer and cannot be opened in this version (Version 8 service Pack 4 Fix Pack 136)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option to downgrade the project. Once the project is opened in the old version, then there is noway you can open the same project in the old versioned visualizer. I suggest you to upgrade your visualizer and keep using it as the mentioned versions are not that different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Kony Visualizer Version 9 Service Pack 3 Fix Pack 4 but actually all the Kony products have been migrated to HCL Volt MX products.

So the current official products are HCL Volt MX Iris 9.2.X (instead of Kony Visualizer 9.2.X) and HCL Volt MX Foundry 9.2.X (instead of Kony Mobile Fabric 9.2.X).

It seems that you are using a non supported product.

Plus, the fact that you cannot downgrade a project made with Kony/HCL products...

Cordially,
Hervé N.